# How to delay Rails controller action until Stripe's webhook has succeeded?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stripe-payments, webhooks

In my Stripe implementation a user can add new [payment methods](https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_methods) like this:

```
class PaymentMethodsController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @payment_methods = current_account.payment_methods
  end

  def new
    setup_intent = Stripe::SetupIntent.create({
      :payment_method_types => ['card', 'sepa_debit'],
      :customer => current_account.stripe_id
    })
    @client_secret = setup_intent.client_secret
  end

  def create
    flash[:success] = "Payment method created."
    redirect_to payment_methods_path
  end

end
```

(The exact implementation doesn't matter much here, though.)

I am also storing copies of each user's payment methods in my database, in order to be able to show them to the user in the `index` view of my controller.

The problem is now that I am using Stripe's webhooks to create these database entries and that it usually takes a couple of seconds for these webhooks to hit my app.

So when I redirect my user to the list of payment methods (`payment_methods_path`) after they created a new one, the latest payment method is usually not visible there which is very confusing. Only when the user reloads their page, the new entry will become visible (because Stripe's webhook will have succeeded by then).

Is there a way to *delay* a Rails controller action until a certain webhook has succeeded or even delay it by a fixed number of seconds (e.g. 5)?

I am facing the same issue with my Subscriptions which are being created locally only after the webhook has succeeded. Until then my users are still in the **Free** plan for a couple of seconds which is not a *massive* problem but still very confusing to many of my users.

What is the best way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to delay a Rails controller action until a certain webhook has succeeded or even delay it by a fixed number of seconds (e.g. 5)?

**Yes.** But its a bad idea. You can delay sending the response by simply telling the server to [sleep](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.1/Kernel.html#method-i-sleep). However this is NOT what you want as it may cause the client to time out the connection and will tie up the thread on your webserver.

The classic solution to this problem is [polling](https://davidwalsh.name/javascript-polling) or [long polling](https://javascript.info/long-polling) where you use JavaScript to send repeated XHR requests nagging the server until whatever it is that you're waiting for has finished. Long polling removes the cost involved with setting up new connections but requires the server to allow a large number of simultaineus connections.

Nowadays you can use [WebSockets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSocket) which allows a duplex connection. This has has built in support in Rails in the form of [ActionCable](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_cable_overview.html). [server-sent-events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Server-sent_events/Using_server-sent_events) is also an alternative but which requires you to roll your own to a larger degree.

Answer (score 1):

You can also make the code in your webhook and in your return URL idempotent; i.e., either one can create the thing.  That way it doesn't matter which happens first, and since you have the webhook, it will definitely happen eventually.